# How do I inject a logger into MediatR command handlers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mediatr, mediator

I am attempting to debug a web application that uses the Mediator design pattern via the MediatR package. I have a logger in the web API controller, but because of the nature of the design pattern, I don't know how I can pass that logger from the controller to the command, and then into the command handler. I'm all but certain this is down to inexperience on my part - what am I missing here?

Comment: Well, that's rude. I didn't write the code I'm maintaining, and Googling "mediatr inject" didn't get me much in the way of code examples. If you're referring to this documentation: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki , again, very little in the way of code examples for what I'm trying to do. Your answer boils down to "Google it, you moron". If this were an easy question to Google, I would have done that. But as I said, I am inexperienced and don't know the magic words.

Answer (score 1):

In your handler(s), grab an instance of ILogger from the DI container, assuming you’ve added logging.

E.g. https://github.com/microsoft/AspNetCore-React-WebApp/blob/main/service/Microsoft.DSX.ProjectTemplate.Data/Services/EmailService.cs

Does this help?